# Is there any way to disable and then enable a client.event() in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have client.event() in my Discord Bot code. I'm trying to build a way to disable it because my bot can get annoying at times. However, I only want to disable and enable the events. Is it possible to do so and if so, what is the code for it?

Comment: inside function you could put code in `if run_event_1:` and use global variable `run_event_1 = False` or `run_event_1 = True` to control this event. The same you can do with other functions using other global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea for this would be to use cogs.

using this bit of code here:

NOTE: You **need** the command module - `from discord.ext import commands`

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def load(ctx, extension):
    await ctx.send('Succesfully been enabled!')
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    await ctx.send('Succesfully been disabled!')
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
```

You will be able to load and unload files. So put the event in a cog and then unload/load it whenever you'd like!

I do suggest to learn cogs if you haven't already